# Обрабатывать нажатия на картинки

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть масив

```
PictureBox[,] picture = new PictureBox[20, 20];
```

Создаю 20 картинок в масиве и вывожу их на панель

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{
    picture[i, j] = new PictureBox();

    picture[i, j].BackColor = Color.Azure;
    picture[i, j].Location = new Point(40 * i, 40 * j);
    panel1.Controls.Add(picture[i, j]);
}
```

Как мне узнать и сменить цвет той картинке из массива, на которой кликнут мышкой?

Comment: бизнес-идея: компьютерные мыши в форме других животных (мишек, например).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{
  ...
  picture[i, j].Click += PictureBoxClick;
}


private void PictureBoxClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender is PictureBox)
  {
    ((PictureBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Comment: на пару секунд опередил с ответом =)

Comment: @rdorn - Не смог устоять перед названием вопроса :)

Comment: Спасибо! Бизнес-идея хороша :D